# Using Multiple Handler Events At One Time

Tags: vb.net, validation

How can I rewrite the following code so that instead of rewriting 15 times, I can use only one sub:

```
Private Sub txtQuestionValue01_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtQuestionValue01.Leave
    txtQuestionValue01.Text = txtQuestionValue01.Text.TrimStart("0"c)
End Sub
```

The goal is that since each textbox is assigned a number 1 through 20, I want to rewrite it so that it looks for `txtQuestionValue02.Leave` and onward to `txtQuestionValue20.Leave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them like this:

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtQuestionValue01.Leave, txtQuestionValue02.Leave
    DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.TrimStart("0"c)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can `DirectCast` also be used for comparisons in a similar manner?

Comment: How exactly do you mean?

Comment: Using the same sub, can I compare the value of `DirectCast` to a conditional. Like if I wanted to check if the textbox I just left is empty?

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, TextBox)` is a direct reference to the actual TextBox that triggered the `Leave` event. So you can do everything that you'd normally be able to do on a TextBox. It's probably best to store the result of `DirectCast` in a temporary variable if you're going to use it extensively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same event handler for all events:

```
Handles txtQuestionValue01.Leave, txtQuestion02.Leave, txtQuestionValue03.Leave....
```